# Finding $\det(X).$

Tags: determinant

So, the question is to find $\det(X)$ if $2X^T = A^{-1}BA$, where $T$ indicates a transpose, given that $A,B,X$ are $4\times 4$ matrices where $\det(A) = 4$ and $\det(B^{-1}) = 3$. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How would you go about doing this? Step by step, but with some work of yourself. Take the left hand side first. How can we get rid of $2$. Then search for $\det(X^T)$ in terms of $\det (X)$.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear at all. The main gripe i have with this question is that it is giving me an equation to find X, and not $\det(X)$. In the question, I do not see $\det(X)$ anywhere so I'm stuck at that part.

To be more specific - How would I convert an expression of $X = ABA$ if there are no determinants present?

Comment: You would convert $X=ABA$ by seeing the determinant in the question "So, the question is to find $\det(X)$ if ...". Then the next step would be to think about applying $\det$ to the equation $X=ABA$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

Start by taking determinant on both sides.

Properties that might be helpful:

- $\det(AB)= \det(A)\det(B)$
- $\det(A^{-1})=\frac1{\det(A)}$
- $\det(X)=\det(X^T)$
- $\det(cX)=c^n\det(X)$.

Comment: The problem above wants me to find $\det(X)$. Do I actually have to find a numerical value, or just $\det(X)$ multiplied by a number $a$, based on the information given?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: An exact numerical value can be obtained.

Comment: So, using the values for $\det(A)$ and $\det(B)$, if $X$ = $AB$, How would I solve for $\det(X)$?

Comment: you are asking an entirely different question, the question is not asking you to find $X$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write the question down properly.

I am sorry to waste your time.

Comment: if $X=AB$, use the first property that I stated.

Comment: oh my god. I just realized you can take the determinant of both sides. I realize my mistake, thank you.

should I delete this question?

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8528/306553 it is usually advisable not to delete a question after it is answered.  Leaving the question here helps others who have similar doubt as you.